# Able to assign properties to a null variable in PHP - is this expected behaviour?

Tags: php, casting

These days I had to fix a bug and stumbled upon a thing that can easily be reproduced:

```
$ php -a
> $test = null;
> $test->prop = 'value';
> print_r($test);
stdClass Object
(
    [prop] => 'value'
)
```

On the console it shows some warnings, but no errors. `null` is just implicitly converted to a `stdClass` object.

Is this documented and expected behaviour, or am I getting something wrong here? Why is it like this?

Comment: "Creating default object from empty value" is a feature, not a bug… *cough cough* It works the same if you don't declare `$test` at all. `null` is equivalent to "empty" for most intents and purposes PHP cares about (except when it doesn't), so it's not too strange that default-object-creation-for-empty-value kicks in in this case. It's debatable whether this is a great idea to have in the first place obviously…

Comment: This fits into the php logic in my eyes: it tries to implicitly allow things. For example you can also define dynamic properties in object by simply assigning a value to them. Same is what you do here: your syntax expresses: I want to assign a value to an object property. Since `$test` is not an object php creates one. That is just the dynamic approach.

Comment: If it is »debatable«, what would be a pro argument?

Comment: *crickets, crickets*…

Comment: If we leave aside the implications this creates I'd say the pro arguments are: that you are able to do that without having to declare or instantiate something when it is obvious what you are trying to do.

Comment: what are your error reporting levels?

Comment: Even Javascript throws errors in such a case, what is what I would call: »expected behaviour«

Comment: @arkascha *"you can also define dynamic properties in object by simply assigning a value to them"* – that's not quite in the same ballpark. If you couldn't do this, if you had to pre-declare all objects as classes with predefined properties, then objects in PHP would play a very different role… In most dynamically typed languages objects are just key-value containers, which can be dynamically created.

Comment: @philipp If you want to discuss about design sensibilities, you've picked the wrong language to argue about. ;-) – Seriously, it is what it is. Somebody decided that it was a good idea. We live with it today.

Comment: @deceze I never claimed it is the same thing. I said it follows the same logic: dynamic creation.

Comment: @deceze But can at least try to make it better in upcoming releases. Starting out by arguing if this was a good decision is my itension.

Comment: @arkascha Sure, just saying that setting a key on an object, and implicitly creating an object out of thin air, are IMO rather different…

Comment: @philipp This is the wrong "forum" for a discussion though. You should partake in the PHP RFC process if you really want to move this forward.

Comment: @deceze well than I will post there…

Comment: By the way, what works without giving a warning is `$test = (object) null;`

Comment: [Smiley](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tSgjmoO7EOU/U5ifcJrygGI/AAAAAAAAI2I/dKX21MFT2Go/s1600/question-smiley.png)?